# Oracle SQL SELECT equivalent to multiple AND

Tags: sql, oracle, join, relational-division

maybe you can help me. I actually study SQL on ORACLE Platform and i have several exercises.

One of them is to hard for me, i don´t get it done right...

This is the Excercise:
Which Countrys are member in ALL organisations, where also Country *XY* is member of?

I have multiple tables but i think only one is necessary for this task.

Tablename: isMember ( abbreviation(fk), country(fk) )

So the Tables looks like:

```
Country   /  Abbreviation
    USA   /      G-5
    USA   /      G-7
    USA   /      G-9
   Canada /      G-7
   Canada /      G-9
   Norway /      G-20
```

and so on....

How can i find every country in the list which is also member of ALL organizations where for example USA is member of?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `Which Countrys are member in ALL organisations, where also Country XY is` . So, in your example, if XY Country is USA, then  none of another countries shouldn't output. Is this correct ?

Comment: Hello Oto, yes correct, in my example is no country which will match. Maybe not the best example but i think it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky question.  One method is to construct all rows with countries and organization the US is in.  Then, count the number each country has and see if they match:

```
select c.country
from (select distinct country from isMember) c cross join
     (select abbreviation from isMember where country = 'USA') a left join
     isMember im
     on im.country = c.country and im.abbreviation = a.abbreviation
group by c.country
having count(*) = count(im.country);  -- do all organizations match?
```

Comment: Hello Gordon, i have checked the SQL code you have posted. I think it doesn´t work like expected. I always find only the country i compare with. In your code the USA for example.

Comment: @eneR . . . In your sample data, no country is a member of all the organizations the US is in.  So, only getting USA is not surprising.